# Bokeh - get updated data when using Edit Tools

Tags: plot, bokeh, interactive

Recently, multi-gesture [edit tools](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#edit-tools) have been added to Bokeh. For example, using the script below, I can interactively draw points in a jupyter notebook using the PointDrawTool. My question is, how do I get the updated data for the points that I generate or edit into a numpy array or a similar data structure?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, Column
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

# Direct output to notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=[],
           title='Point Draw Tool')
p.background_fill_color = 'lightgrey'

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': [1, 5, 9], 'y': [1, 5, 9], 'color': ['red', 'green', 'yellow']
})

renderer = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='color', size=10)
columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
           TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
           TableColumn(field='color', title='color')]
table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, editable=True, height=200)

draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer], empty_value='black')
p.add_tools(draw_tool)
p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

handle = show(Column(p, table), notebook_handle=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using such method of showing plot does not provide synchronization between Python and JS. To solve this you can use bookeh server, as described [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html). Usualy you use commnad:

```
bokeh serve --show myapp.py
```

Then you can embed this application in your jupyter. For me it was very inconvinient so I started to look for other solutions.

**It is possible to run bookeh app from jupyter notebook**, you can find example [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb).

Sample code for your problem would look like this:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show, Column
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

def modify_doc(doc): 
    p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=[],
           title='Point Draw Tool')
    p.background_fill_color = 'lightgrey'
    source = ColumnDataSource({
        'x': [1, 5, 9], 'y': [1, 5, 9], 'color': ['red', 'green', 'yellow']
    })
    renderer = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='color', size=10)
    columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
               TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
               TableColumn(field='color', title='color')]
    table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, editable=True, height=200)

    draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer], empty_value='black')
    p.add_tools(draw_tool)
    p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

    doc.add_root(Column(p, table))

show(modify_doc)
```